# How to modify password change mail made with Laravel auth?

Tags: php, laravel, email, frameworks, passwords

In **Laravel Framework 5.4.18** I just ran `php artisan make:auth`

When I request to reset my password, I get an email that says

(...)

> You are receiving this email because we received a password reset
>   request for your account

(...)

Where is the file where it is specified to say that? I want to change it completely.

**Notice that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441500/change-default-laravel-email-template-theme-sent-to-gmail-or-hotmail) is how to change (only) the general appearance of any notification, and that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43447034/7729561) is how to change (in addition) the body of the notification.**

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default laravel email template theme sent to gmail or hotmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441500/change-default-laravel-email-template-theme-sent-to-gmail-or-hotmail)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `User` model uses the `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword` trait. This trait has the following function:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    // use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

When a password reset is requested, this method is called and uses the `ResetPassword` notification to send out the email.

If you would like to modify your reset password email, you can create a new custom `Notification` and define the `sendPasswordResetNotification` method on your `User` model to send your custom `Notification`. Defining the method directly on the `User` will take precedence over the method included by the trait.

Create a notification that extends the built in one:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;

class YourCustomResetPasswordNotification extends ResetPassword
{
    /**
     * Build the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('This is your custom text above the action button.')
            ->action('Reset Password', route('password.reset', $this->token))
            ->line('This is your custom text below the action button.');
    }
}
```

Define the method on your `User` to use your custom notification:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new YourCustomResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First open a terminal and go to the root of the application and run the following command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

You will see some files copied, you can find the email template files in

```
Root_Of_App/resources/views/vendor
```

You can edit the Email templates for notifications there.