# Change default laravel email template theme sent to gmail or hotmail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

This is default email generated and sent by laravel using smtp , and i want to change this default template like adding some pictures,url...
how can i do that? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Run `php artisan vendor:publish` and navigate to `resources/views/vendor/notifications` then now you have two files, edit them.

Answer (score 5):

Here i am only showing how can you change the default Laravel logo from your mail template

first step is to publish our Mail components inside our resource folder so that we can change the default configuration .

run the following command .

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

Now this command will create a vendor folder inside your app/resources/views directory .

now you can provide your image path in the mail template to use your custom image on Mail as shown in the following code

```
    @component('mail::layout')
{{-- Header --}}
@slot('header')
@component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
{{-- {{ config('app.name') }} --}}

<img src="{{asset('storage/logo/logo.jpg')}}" style="height: 75px;width: 75px;">

@endcomponent
@endslot

{{-- Body --}}
{{ $slot }}

{{-- Subcopy --}}
@isset($subcopy)
@slot('subcopy')
@component('mail::subcopy')
{{ $subcopy }}
@endcomponent
@endslot
@endisset

{{-- Footer --}}
@slot('footer')
@component('mail::footer')
© {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. @lang('All rights reserved.')
@endcomponent
@endslot
@endcomponent
```

For more information you can visit [here](https://www.studywithkishan.online/2020/11/change-default-mail-logo-laravel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not actually use any email template, instead it builds the email directly using `MailMessage` like this

```php
return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
            ->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
            ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), $url)
            ->line(Lang::get('This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')]))
            ->line(Lang::get('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
```

So to override this, in any of your Service Providers, I will go with `AuthServiceProvider`, add the following:

```php
// use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;
// ...


ResetPassword::toMailUsing(function ($notifiable, $token) {
            $email = $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset();

            
            $emailResetUrl = url(route('password.reset', [
                    'token' => $token,
                    'email' => $email,
                ], false));
            
            // this is where you generate your own email
            return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
                ->view('email.auth.reset-password', [
                    'url' => $emailResetUrl
                ]);
        });
```

Or you learn more from this article, https://medium.com/@josephajibodu/how-to-customize-laravel-fortify-authentication-email-templates-21b6a315e279

Answer (score -1):

While generating the auth using `make:auth`, it will generate the required views in the `resources/view/auth` folder.

You can customize the `resources/views/auth/emails/password.blade.php` page as you required. You can add images and url as asked

for more details  [here is the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passwords#resetting-views)

Comment: thanks for reply,I'm not talking about the page who contain inputs to enter email...(views)But i want to change the email template sent when i click on recover password button